# Step thumbnails scrolling in Fotorama

Tags: jquery, gallery, photo-gallery, fotorama

Is there a way to scroll thumbnails in Fotorama plugin with fixed step? I need to remove those 'uncuts', half of thumbnail on sides of nav panel. [image]

I can fit them using margin/padding properties, but I can't control process of scrolling with drag'n'drop, when it can stop anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment you can not control over position of navigation shaft with Fotorama API.

When you click on the thumb next one comes to your cursor. So you don’t have to move cursor and this uncuts are side-effect in this scenario.

Comment: Hi @Art . Can you please look on that => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034310/fotorama-if-class-disabled-found-in-thumbnail-then-display-next-image-except-d